# my ubuntu 12.04 takes hours before it load

Tags: 12.04, grub2

firstly it started with not loading on time,showing different errors when starting up..errors like:

```
error couldnt load files
error hd0 out of disk' 
unknow files system grub rescue
```

and so on but it will later load eventually..,..but recently it stated hard pressing the dot key (.) it self continuously and when i try to delete it using <kbd>Del</kbd> key it wouldn't stop but rather continue the dot key like dis .....................continuously, but that doesn't happen if I log on to my window 7 partition. Later mouse insnt working on it and later both Ubuntu and window are not loading again until now that my Ubuntu just load in and working properly, ..what do u guys think is going on and what can I do to stop it when it start again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Ubuntu 14.04 will most likely solve your problem. However I would also suggest checking your partitions for errors, it looks like you may have a few HDD errors(IE: running out of space, broken files, ect...).

Comment: how can i update  to ubuntu 14.04 and how to i check for the partition errors

Comment: You can update to Ubuntu 14.04 by downloading this and burning it to a DVD/USB drive: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. To check your partitions for errors do the above step, then use the included "Disks" utility to check the "SMART" status of your disk.